# Appium XCUITEST 1.7.2 running automation very slow

Tags: appium-ios, xcuitest

I am using Appium v1.7.2 w/ XCUITest and Xcode v9.2 on Mac Sierra. The automation is being run on a physical iPhone 6. Test cases are executed very slowly and take a tremendous amount time to find elements and perform actions as compared to Android.

Is there any way iOS automation can be made faster?

Comment: Try it on iPhone 7

Comment: Does it has to do with OS version of device. Currently it is 10.3.3. We do not have iPhone7 test device for now.

Comment: Yes. Update to 11.x and try it. But still iPhone 6 will be slow once update to latest os

Comment: Thank you. I will check for iPhone7 and compare time of execution.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with iPhone 8 plus (OS Version 11.2.6). Please suggest some help.